# Error - Django project deploy on Railway connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed:

Tags: python, django, web, deployment, railway

I am trying to deploy in my Django project on the Railway site, the pages that do not load images are working, such as login or contact page, but the news page does not load and accuses this error, I have already created the file Procfile, runtime and requirements

connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTfYQ.png)

**settings.py**

```
 import os
    from pathlib import Path
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+#b1$1x)7pt)jn465hgm@tv(ed+4xeahn8=mw^h4l$j0$e+qq3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'contato.apps.ContatoConfig',
    'cursos.apps.CursosConfig',
    'autenticacao.apps.AutenticacaoConfig',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'contas.apps.ContasConfig',
    'widget_tweaks',
    # Requerido allauth
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "blog",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "1234",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
       "PORT": "5432",
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=blog_db'
                },
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/'),
]

MEDIA_URL = 'images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'



LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# google config
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'carusothales@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'eubijjjhliuqwmfw'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'default from email'


SITE_ID = 1
```

**blog.html**

```
{% extends "blog_base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-xl-6">
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% include "fragments/card_base.html" with post=post %}
            <div class="my-3"></div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-data_publicacao')[:5]
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }

    return render(request,'blog/home.html', context)


def post_detail(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    context = {
        'post': post
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)

def blog(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-data_publicacao')[:5]
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.